# Replace integers in dataframe column w/ 'Y'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe w/ two columns: Account, Bought Food that I created with a pivot table to condense each account into one row. Right now it is showing me the total food bought as a number, but can I have alter the data to to show just a 'Y' where there is an integer (I am already using the fillna function to replace NaN w/ No).

Example:

Current:
AcctNo BoughtFood
1ABC 5
2ABD N
3DBC 7

Want:
AcctNo BoughtFood
1ABC Y
2ABD N
3DBC Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create boolean mask by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stble/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) + [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) or `apply` + `isinstance`:

```
#if all data strings, also numeric
m = pd.to_numeric(df['BoughtFood'], errors='coerce').notnull()
```

```
#if mixed df - numeric with strings
m = ~df['BoughtFood'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))
#or
m = df['BoughtFood'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float)))
```

And then set values by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df.loc[m, 'BoughtFood'] = 'T'
print (df)
  AcctNo BoughtFood
0   1ABC          T
1   2ABD          N
2   3DBC          T
```

---

```
df['BoughtFood'] = df['BoughtFood'].mask(m, 'T')
print (df)
  AcctNo BoughtFood
0   1ABC          T
1   2ABD          N
2   3DBC          T
```

Solution for multiple columns:

```
cols = ['BoughtFood','BoughtWater']
m = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).notnull()
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(m, 'T')
print (df)
  AcctNo BoughtFood BoughtWater
0   1ABC          T           N
1   2ABD          N           T
2   3DBC          T           T
```

Comment: Unknowing I ended up in the same solution :) +1

Comment: Thank you very much, can this be done on multiple columns?  Say I added a 'Bought Water' column as well?